# Microsoft word call C# Clipboard change event after closing

Tags: c#, clipboard

In my *winform* application in C#, I'm using this code to do something when windows Clipboard contents changes.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

private const int WmClipboardupdate = 0x031D;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  base.WndProc(ref m);
  if (m.Msg != WmClipboardupdate) return;
  richText.Paste();
}
```

Now when I copy some text from `Microsoft Word`, it works fine. But the problem is when I close `Word application`, it still calls the change event 3 times and the text in the clipboard pastes in to my RichTextBox or wherever I use the Clipboard content.
Does anyone has any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: I guess every time Clipboard is updated, there are more than _one_  `WmClipboardupdate` events fired. So, a better approach is filtering the messages in WndProc - Do not call `richText.Paste();` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your listener to stop receiving events.

```
RemoveClipboardFormatListener(hwnd);
```

how do you know when an unrelated application is open?

```
    private bool IsWordFileOpened()
    {
       bool isExist = false;
       System.Diagnostics.Process[] prs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();        
       foreach (Process pr in prs)
       {
          if (pr.ProcessName == "WINWORD")
          {
            isExist = true;
            break;
          }
       }
       return isExist;
    }
```

or subscribe to closing even using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CBTProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), HCBT_DESTROYWND.

But this is a hack. I would suggest you probably are doing something wrong. I'm not sure I understand your requirements, but you should have your winforms application do it's thing during the lifetime of the winforms application.

Comment: Information about `CBTProc callback function` can be helpful, but your code can't. Cause there might be more `WINWORD`s open in windows and also this issue can happens for some other applications. thanks anyway